# Apply border to html elements using externally linked CSS

Tags: html, css

Why am I having difficulties bordering an HTML element through externally linked CSS file? Help!
The code in my HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='n.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section  id='1id' class='2class 3class 4class'>
      I am bordered & got 1 ID & 3 classes,oh ye!
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

How my n.css file looks:

```
<style>
  #1id {border:2;}
  .2class{text-decoration:underline;}
  .3class{text-style:italic;}
  .4class{font-weight:bold;}
</style>
```

Comment: You don't need to put the `<style>` tag in the css file, only when inside the html file.

Comment: Thank you @LinusGeffarth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*First you have to understand some points to fix your code*

**1.** don't use `<style>` tag in your `.css` file...use it if you are writing your css in `.html` file

**2.** there is no `text-style` property in css...use `font-style` instead

**3.** It is not a good practice to use a number at starting to the `id` and `class` *(Here is also solution for the `id` and `class` starting with number)*

**4.** you have used invalid value for `border` i.e. `border:2`...use `border:2px solid currentcolor`

> *Note: Also for better coding don't use multiple classes on the same element to styling...you can apply multiple styles at same class*

---

***Solution1*** *(`id` and `class` does not start with numbers)*

***Stack Snippet***

```css
#id1 {
  border: 2px solid currentcolor;
}

.class2 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.class3 {
  font-style: italic;
}

.class4 {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section id='id1' class='class2 class3 class4'>
  I have 3 classes and 1 id oh ye!
</section>
```

---

***Solution2*** *(`id` and `class` starts with numbers)*

## How id differs in between HTML 4.01 and HTML5

> *The **HTML 4.01** spec states that **ID** tokens must begin with a letter **([A-Za-z])** and may be followed by any number of **letters**, **digits ([0-9])**, **hyphens (-)**, **underscores (_)**, **colons (:)**, and **periods (.)**. For the class attribute, there is no such limitation. Classnames can contain any character, and they don’t have to start with a letter to be valid.*
>
> *HTML5 gets rid of the additional restrictions on the **id** attribute. The only requirements left — apart from being **unique** in the document — are that the value must contain **at least one character** (can’t be empty), and that it can’t contain any **space characters**.*
>
> *This means the rules that apply to values of **class** and **id** attributes are now very similar in **HTML5**.*
>
> - ***[Reference for id starts with special character](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/html5-id)***
> - ***[Reference for class starts with special character](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/crazy-class)***

Here you have to add the `\3` prefix to the number and a space after that.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
#\31 id {
  border: 2px solid currentcolor;
}

.\32 class {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.\33 class {
  font-style: italic;
}

.\34 class {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section id='1id' class='2class 3class 4class'>
  I have 3 classes and 1 id oh ye!
</section>
```

Comment: Appreciate your help! Sir!

Comment: @Dr.Anonymous Glad..!...it helped you..

Answer (score 0):

you can set border in externally css same as internally css 
like m supposing your .2class one more thing try to start class name with letters.

```
.2class{ border:1px solid black;}
```

it gives you black border outside your .2class

Comment: did you tested before post your answer?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hackstarsj/wx06tb2m/1/

Comment: your jsfiddle one more thing css selector not select the class with start with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#1id{
    border:2px solid #999;
    padding:10px;
}
.section{
    float:left;
    padding:0 5px;
    margin:-20px 0 0 30px;
    background:#fff;
}
```

Comment: did you tested before post your answer?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `<style>` tag from your external css
2. your css is not taking because you have started the id and class with number in that case you have to write like this for HTML5

**Example id='1id'**

```
[id="1id"] { border : 2px solid #000; }
```

**Example class='2class'**

```
[class='2class']{font-weight:bold;}
```

> You can not use more than 1 class which started with number like class='2class 3class 4class'

```css
[id="1id"] { border : 2px solid #000; }
[class='2class']{font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<section  id='1id' class='2class'>
I have 1 id and 1 class oh ye!
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main mistake was `#1id {border:2;}`
which got corrected by adding `'solid color'` and `'px'-` to:

```
#id1{border:2px solid currentcolor;}
```

The other two sub-mistakes were using `<style></style>` in a css file, and starting ID's and CLASSES with a number like 1id, 2class, etc. The correct way of starting ID's and CLASSES is like id1, class2, etc.