# Website CSS stylesheet not applying completely

Tags: html, css, web

Ok someone help me with creating my first website. The problem is that the stylesheet only applies partly.

[image: How its supposed to look/how it looks locally]

[image: How it actually looks]
My body

```
<div class="top1">
    <h1 align="left" class="1logo">La Di Da DI</h1> 
    <h1 align="left" class="2logo">we likes to party</h1></div>

</body>
```

My stylesheet

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    outline-offset: 0px;
    background-color: #FFEAE5;
}
.mainTitle{
    display: inline;
}
.2logo {
    display: inline;
    color: #FFEAE5;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: italic;
}
.1logo {
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    display: inline;
    color: #FFEAE5;
}
.top1 {
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background-color: #F87666;
    }
```

Stylesheet link

```
<link href="main.css" content"text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a number at the starting of the `class` is not a good practice because it takes a different approach to apply css to that kind of class...

Try to remove the numbers from the starting and put it at end like:

**HTML**

```
<div class="top1">
  <h1 align="left" class="logo1">La Di Da DI</h1>
  <h1 align="left" class="logo2">we likes to party</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  outline-offset: 0px;
  background-color: #FFEAE5;
}

.mainTitle {
  display: inline;
}

.logo2 {
  display: inline;
  color: #FFEAE5;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.logo1 {
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: inline;
  color: #FFEAE5;
}

.top1 {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  background-color: #F87666;
}
```

> ***[If you are looking for a solution that how to apply `css` to `class` that starts from a number see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48801100/apply-border-to-html-elements-using-externally-linked-css/48802304#48802304)***

Comment: Wouldnt have guessed that the problem was so simple. Thank you.

Comment: @Jaypaque Glad it helped you....don't forget to accept and upvote the answer if this resolved your issue...